# Using a drawable instead of the color code stops the app

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-databinding

My app works just fine when I use a color code for my Buttons background in my layout. Something like:

```
android:background="#ff6699"
```

But it stops working when I replace the color code with my drawable:

```
android:background="@drawable/blue_background_round_corners"
```

This means, there is obviously something wrong with my drawable. Any idea what?
My drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ff6699"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

by the way, I am using data binding. My fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
FragmentMainBinding binding;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    View v = binding.getRoot();
    v.setClickable(true);
    v.setFocusable(true);
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: If by "stops the app", you mean that the app is crashing, use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Your drawable' s code is working fine.

Comment: Are you intentionally using a `StateListDrawable` using `selector` ?